# Communication between 2 Lagom service (running on two different servers/machines), over Kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, lagom

I am trying to learn/understand scala+lagom+kafka in detail. While searching through the web found a sample Twitter project that explains it  pretty nicely (https://github.com/knoldus/lagom-scala.g8/tree/master/src/main/g8). In this project two Lagom microservices (consumer & producer) are created and they communicate over a kafka topic. However both the service run on the same server/machine.

I was wondering if it is possible to have communication between two lagom+kafka microservice running on two different servers/machines using kafka topic. I was able to achieve this configuration by simple kafka (without Lagom), by modifying kafka configuration files (zookeeper.properties and server.properties).

**Questions:**

1. Is this configuration (producer and consumer on two different servers) possible using Lagom+Kafka.
2. How do I add kafka configuration (zookeeper.properties and server.properties) inside lagom framework.
3. Is there any project that utilizes above configuration. So that, I can use this as a reference to understand Lagom+Kafka in easily.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this configuration (producer and consumer on two different servers) possible using Lagom+Kafka.

Of course, Yes.

> 2.How do I add kafka configuration (zookeeper.properties and server.properties) inside lagom framework.

There's documentation about that:

- https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/KafkaClient.html
- https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/KafkaServer.html

> Is there any project that utilizes above configuration. So that, I can use this as a reference to understand Lagom+Kafka in easily.

There're some example projects in the Lagom Github:

- https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala
- https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java

Philosophically, it's because Lagom services are hosted on different servers (so are separated by networks) that we need Kafka, no matters where Kafka is hosted.
I've already explained this need here: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/need-some-insight-on-lagoms-architecture/1369

Jules

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I had a few followup question:

Comment: 1. Where do we add "lagom.broker.kafka" configuration? Does it go in resources/application.conf?
2. I do not see parameters like "zoo servers", "host.name" & "zookeeper.connect" in https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/ documentation. How do I pass these parameters to Lagom?
3. Do I have to disable in-built kafka and use "external Kafka server" for communication between producer and consumer running on different servers?
4. I skimmed through the "online-auction-scala" project and did not find zookeeper/kafka configuration specifically. Could you please provide some pointers?

Comment: I created a kafka-server.properties configuration file (with required zookeeper & server properties). Added following lines to build.sbt to be able to compile these server properties in my lagom project:
`lagomKafkaPropertiesFile in ThisBuild :=
  Some((baseDirectory in ThisBuild).value / "project" / "kafka-server.properties")`
The broker.id was set to a same value (say "1") on both the lagom service to be able to setup communication between them. Now the next issue that I am working on is to be able to compile the consumer code without the reference of kafka topic created by the Producer.